# how to modify the i-th element of a Haskell List?

Tags: list, haskell

I'm looking for a way to modify the i-th element of haskell List. let says `foobar` is such a function, then the following works.

```
let xs = ["a","b","c","d"]
foobar xs 2 "baba" -- xs = ["a","b","baba","d"]
```

thanks for any reply!

Comment: Keep in mind that if you are doing this sort of random-access-modification, either modifying your algorithm or using a (mutable in the ST monad if possible) vector would be appropriate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with `splitAt`:

```
Prelude> let xs = ["a","b","c","d"]
Prelude> (\(l,_:r)->l++"baba":r) $ splitAt 2 xs
["a","b","baba","d"]
```

Comment: @FOPALéonConstantin: Bear in mind the original list is not modified - a new list is created containing the desired element at the specified position.

Comment: I cannot imagine we have to create a self-made function for such a common paradigm even though in pure functional programming.

Answer (score 3):

```
let xs = ["a","b","c","d"]
take 2 xs ++ ["baba"] ++ drop 3 xs
```

Comment: Probably easier to understand, but I think the behaviour if the list is too short is problematic: in that case `"baba"` is _appended_, whatever position the end is at. (My solution gives an error in that case, also not optimal but easy to fix.) Furthermore, it needs to calculate 3=2+1 and needs to do two list traversals to the desired position, but that performance loss may not matter.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: there are thousands of ways to do that, including manual constructing of the new list element by element. I just took the most elegant I could think of. New element will be added only if list is empty, but behavior of the function is undefined for this case.

Comment: It's _not_ undefined, I wouldn't have complained in that case – but `take n` simply takes the whole list if its length is less than _n_, and `drop n` returns an empty list then. So, e.g., `take 37 xs ++ ["baba"] ++ drop 38 xs` returns `["a","b","c","d","baba"]`, where `"baba"` is nowhere near position 37.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: author of the question asked about only one case, additional conditions were not mentioned and are not obvious. So it _is_ undefined what to do if position to insert element to exceeds length of the list. But if you want particular conditions, you can always add them separately.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought you meant the behaviour of `take` and `drop` were undefined in that case.

Answer (score 2):

```
change n x = zipWith (\k e -> if k == n then x else e) [0..]
```

Comment: Clever, but suboptimal. If you're changing index _k_, the `splitAt` method is _O(k)_, while this one is always _O(n)_. Though I guess it could be argued that if you're worried about speed, you shouldn't be using lists for this in the first place.

Comment: You are right, but I think my version is more flexible (e.g. can be adapted easily to work for multiple indexes).

Comment: @Landei true, however the simplistic approach to this (`... zipWith (\k e -> if elem k nList then ...`) would be even more ineffective: _O_ (_n_ ⋅ _l_) while max( _O_ (_n_), _O_ (_l_ ln(_l_) ) ) is achievable.

Comment: Putting the indices in a set would be good enough for many applications.

Answer (score 2):

A simple function to do it directly:

```
replaceAt _ _ []     = []
replaceAt 0 x (_:ys) = x:ys
replaceAt n x (y:ys) = y:replaceAt (n - 1) x ys
```