# How to make a pattern of ticktack game in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, tuples, list-comprehension

Implement the function ticktack which has 2 arguments. First argument is a tuple of natural numbers and defines the number of rows and columns of a play field. Second list contains a record of a match of ticktacktoe game given by coordinates on which played in turns player 'x' and player 'o'. Print actual state of the game in the way where play-field will be bordered by characters '-' and '|', empty squares ' ' and characters 'x' and 'o' will be on squares where the players have played.

```
ticktack::(Int,Int) -> [(Int,Int)] -> Result
```

I already tried something like this:

```
type Result = [String]
pp :: Result -> IO ()
pp x = putStr (concat (map (++"\n") x))

ticktack::(Int,Int) -> [(Int,Int)] -> Result
ticktack (0,0) (x:xs) = []
ticktack (a,b) [] = []
ticktack (a,b) (x:xs) =[ [if a == fst x && b == snd x then 'x' else ' ' | b <- [1..b]]| a <- [1..a]] ++ ticktack (a,b) xs
```

But it returns me only N [Strings] with 1 result, so i need these results merge into one [String].

Comment: You could either merge the outputs with a double `zipWith` (rather messy, since you'll be comparing output characters), or you could search the history once for each space in the board.  That is, use some auxiliary function `getLocation :: [(Int, Int)] -> (Int, Int) -> Char` (where the second `(Int,Int)` is a *position*).

Comment: @luqui Thanks for your answer. But could you please tell me how could this modification with double zipWith look like? I am still new to haskell, so any examples of code could really help me.

Comment: on the final line: `zipWith (zipWith mergeChar) [ [ if a == fst x ... ] ] (ticktack (a,b) xs)`.  That is, instead of concatenating (`++`) the boards generated from the remainder of the moves, we "zip-merge" them.   Here `mergeChar :: Char -> Char -> Char` is a function you write that will, for example, take `' '` and `'x'` and give `'x'` -- how to combine each location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @luqui says in a comment to the question:

> You could either merge the outputs ... or you could search the history once for each space in
>   the board. ...

The former solution is [described in a nearby question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58685116). The *"chess"* problem having been
solved there is only superficially distinct from your *"noughts & crosses"* problem, so it should
not be too hard to adapt the solution. However:

- In that case, the board size is fixed and small, so we were not worried about the inefficiency
  of merging the boards pairwise.
- In this case, the board size is variable, so a solution by the latter method may be worth a try.

To make the algorithm even more efficient, instead of scrolling across the board and searching for
matching moves at every cell, we will scroll across the moves and assign values to a board
represented as a mutable array. Mutable arrays may be considered an *"advanced technique"* in
functional programming, so it could also be a good exercise for an intermediate Haskeller. I only
used them once or twice before, so let us see if I can figure this out!

### How is this going to work?

At the heart of the program will be a rectangular array of bytes. An array goes in two flavours:
mutable and *"frozen"*. While a frozen array cannot be changed, It is a rule that a mutable array
may only exist in a monadic context, so we can only freely pass around an array when it is frozen.
If this seems to be overcomplicated, I can only ask the reader to believe that the additional
safety guarantees are worth this complication.

Anyway, here are the types:

```
type Position = (Int, Int)

type Field s = STUArray s Position Char

type FrozenField = UArray Position Char
```

We will create a function that *"applies"* a list of moves to an array, thawing and freezing it as
needed.

```
type Move = (Char, Position)

applyMoves :: FrozenField -> [Move] -> FrozenField
```

*(The idea of `Move` is that it is sufficient to put a mark on the board, without needing to know
whose turn it is.)*

Applied to an empty field of the appropriate size, this function will solve our problem — we shall
only need to adjust the format of the input and the output.

```
empty :: Position -> FrozenField

positionsToMoves :: [Position] -> [Move]

arrayToLists :: FrozenField -> [[Char]]
```

Our final program will then look like this:

```
tictac :: Position -> [Position] -> IO ()
tictac corner = pp . arrayToLists . applyMoves (empty corner) . positionsToMoves
```

I hope it looks sensible? Even though we have not yet written any tangible code.

### Can we write the code?

Yes.

First, we will need some imports. No one likes imports, but, for some reason, it is not yet
automated. So, here:

```
import Data.Foldable (traverse_)
import Data.Array.Unboxed
import Data.Array.ST
import GHC.ST (ST)
```

The simplest thing one can do with arrays is to create an empty one. Let us give it a try:

```
empty :: Position -> FrozenField
empty corner = runSTUArray (newArray ((1, 1), corner) ' ')
```

The idea is that `newArray` claims a region in memory and fills it with spaces, and `runSTUArray`
freezes it so that it can be safely transported to another part of a program. We could instead
*"inline"* the creation of the array and win some speed, but we only need to do it once, and I
wanted to keep it composable — I think the program will be simpler this way.

Another easy thing to do is to write the *"glue"* code that adjusts the input and output format:

```
positionsToMoves :: [Position] -> [Move]
positionsToMoves = zip (cycle ['x', 'o'])

arrayToLists :: FrozenField -> [[Char]]
arrayToLists u =
  let ((minHeight, minWidth), (maxHeight, maxWidth)) = bounds u
  in [ [ u ! (row, column) | column <- [minWidth.. maxWidth] ] | row <- [minHeight.. maxHeight] ]
```

Nothing unusual here, run-of-the-mill list processing.

Finally, the hard part — the code that applies any number of moves to a given frozen array:

```
applyMoves :: FrozenField -> [Move] -> FrozenField
applyMoves start xs = runSTUArray (foldST applyMove (thaw start) xs)
  where

    foldST :: (a -> b -> ST s ()) -> ST s a -> [b] -> ST s a
    foldST f start' moves = do
        u <- start'
        traverse_ (f u) moves
        return u

    applyMove :: Field s -> Move -> ST s ()
    applyMove u (x, i) = writeArray u i x
```

The pattern is the same as in the function `empty`: modify an array, then freeze it — and all the
modifications have to happen in an `ST` monad, for safety. `foldST` contains all the
*"imperative"* *"inner loop"* of our program.

### *(P.S.)* How does this actually work?

Let us unwrap the `UArray` and `STUArray` types first. What are they and what is the difference?

`UArray` means *"unboxed array"*, which is to say an array of values, as opposed to an array of
pointers. The value in our case is actually a Unicode character, not a C *"byte"* `char`, so it is not a byte, but a variable
size entity. When it is stored in unboxed form, it is converted to an `Int32` and back invisibly
to us. An `Int32` is of course way too much for our humble purpose of storing 3 different values,
so there is space for improvement here. To find out more about unboxed values, I invite you to
check the article that introduced them back in 1991, [*"Unboxed Values as First Class Citizens in
a Non-Strict Functional Language"*](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/1991/01/unboxed-values.pdf).

That the values are unboxed does not mean that you can change them though. A pure value in Haskell
is always immutable. So, were you to change a single value in an array, the whole array would be
copied — expensive! This is where `STUArray` comes in. `ST` stands for `State Thread`, and what
`STUArray` is is an *"unfrozen"* array, where you can overwrite individual values without copying
the whole thing. To ensure safety, it can only live in a monad, in this case the `ST` monad.
*(Notice how an `STUArray` value never appears outside of an `ST s` wrap.)* You can imagine an
`ST` computation as a small imperative process with its own memory, separate from the outside
world. The story goes that they invented `ST` first, and then figured out they can get `IO` from
it, so `IO` is actually `ST` in disguise. For more details on how `ST` works, check out the
original article from 1994: [*"Lazy Functional State Threads"*](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/1994/06/lazy-functional-state-threads.pdf.).

Let us now take a more careful look at `foldST`. What we see is that *functionally*, it does not
make sense. First we bind the value of `start'` to `u`, and then we return `u` — the same
variable. From the functional point of view, this is the same as writing:

```
u <- start'
return u
```

— Which would be equivalent to `u` by monad laws. The trick is in what happens inbetween:

```
traverse_ (f u) moves
```

Let us check the type.

```
λ :type traverse_
traverse_ :: (Foldable t, Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f ()
```

So, some function is being called, with `u` as argument, but the result is the useless `()` type.
In a functional setting, this line would mean nothing. But in a monad, bound values may *appear*
to change. `f` is a function that can change the state of a monad, and so can change the value of
the bound names when they are returned. The analogous code in C would go somewhat like this:

```c
char* foldST(void f(char*, Move), int n_start, char start[], int n_moves, Move moves[])
{
    // u <- start
    char* u = malloc(sizeof(char) * n_start);
    memcpy(u, start, sizeof(char) * n_start);

    // traverse_ (f u) moves
    for (int i = 0; i < n_moves; i++)
    {
        f(u, moves[i]);
    }

    // return u
    return u;
}
```

In Haskell, the pointer arithmetic is abstracted away, but essentially `traverse_` in `ST` works
like this. I am not really familiar with C nor with the inner workings of the `ST` abstraction, so
this is merely an analogy, not an attempt at a precise rendition. Nevertheless I hope it helps the reader to observe the similarity between `ST` and ordinary imperative C code.

### Mission accomplished!

It runs reasonably fast. Takes only a moment to draw a million-step match on a million-sized
board. I hope it is also explained clearly enough. Do not hesitate to comment if something is amiss or unclear.

Comment: Really thanks. Your solucion really helped me with understanding the more complex functions and things in Haskell. I am still learning Haskell, so i got little bit confused in this STUArray and UArray things, so could you please explain me something little about this datatypes and how they work? And i got confused also when i tried to understand `applyMoves` function. But i really appreciate your help man.

Comment: @Weliras Did you look at the other question I linked? It may be more accessible. I also added an explanation of `STUArray` and `foldST`.

Comment: @Weliras Another advice is to try it out in `ghci`, on a small example. Can you create an array of characters, then change one character? Can you change several characters at once?

Comment: Ohh now i see it. Well i'll look into it, this should really help me out. I will also try some smaller tasks with arrays. And i wanted to ask you, if you know about another solucion to this program without arrays in haskell?

Comment: @Weliras Well, you need to store your board somewhere. Whether it is an array, a map, or maybe even a composite function. Certainly there are many options. If you keep working, eventually you will master them all.