# Minesweeper board labels (beginner level)

Tags: list, haskell, minesweeper

We were given a homework, where we get a sample minesweeper-like board, with blank spaces instead of numbers (board is in [String] form) and already placed mines. What we need is to create a function, that replaces all blank spaces with numbers, which are equal to number of adjecent mines.

I was unable of making any real progress, except for removing all spaces with zeroes, which is probably not even useful in any way. I also had a problem with zeroes being of Char type, which made me unable to add for example +1 to it. It would be great if this could be solved without advanced functions, so I can understand it, but any solution or at least idea of solution will do.

This is what the beginning of the code should look like.

```hs
import Data.Char

type Result = [String]

pp :: Result -> IO ()
pp x = putStr (concat (map (++"\n") x)) --prints strings in a column.


sampleInput = ["       ",
               " *     ",
               "    *  ",
               "   *   ",
               "      *",
               "***    ",
               "* *    ",
               "***    "]

minesweeper :: Result -> Result
```

And result should be this

```
Prelude>pp(minesweeper sampleInput)
1110000
1*11110
1122*10
001*221
233211*
***2011
*8*3000
***2000
```

I'm incredibly glad for any guidance as I'm unable of any real progress.

Update: Did a bit different yet similar solution. You can check related question  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58827023/how-to-make-my-function-move-through-two-lists-at-once/58836932#58836932)

Comment: I think this problem was already posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58763683/function-that-replaces-space-with-number-which-represents-stars-around#comment103815110_58763683). I don’t think I can close this as a duplicate though because neither this question nor that one has any answers yet. But I’ll repeat my comment from that question here:

Comment: Here’s some hints: (1) Try create a function which, given a coordinate, returns all the points around that coordinate in a given `Result`; (2) Then try create a function which, given a `Result`, returns a nested list of all coordinates in it (e.g. `["ab","cd"]` becomes `[[(0,0),(0,1)],[(1,0),(1,1)]]`); (3) Try to use these two functions together to solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need here is called *"stencil convolution"*. Look at this picture:

```
111
1x1
111
```

This is your stencil. Pick a tile on the playing board and place the stencil on top of that tile.
How many `1`s overlay mines, that number we should display in this tile. For example:

```
       .....   .....
111    .*...   .....
1x1  + ..x*. = ..3..
111    ...*.   .....
       .....   .....
```

Once we apply this operation to the whole board, we are basically done.

There are advanced devices for this, such as comonads and arrays, but for the purpose of this post
I will keep things simple, so we are going to draft everything by hand, in the simplest types. I
am also going to leave some blanks in the code, so that it is less boring for the reader. If you
enable [`-fdefer-typed-holes`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#typed-holes), you can put things like `_wut` in place of `...` and `ghc`
will tell you what it thinks the type of the hole should be.

---

1. I should like to deal with numbers, rather than characters: as you point out, characters
   are ill-suited for algorithmic work. Conversion should be two way, so that we can display our
   result as well.

   ```
   charsToInts :: [[Char]] -> [[Int]]
   charsToInts = (fmap . fmap) charToInt
     where
       charToInt '*' = ...
       charToInt ... = ...

   intsToChars :: [[Int]] -> [[Char]]
   intsToChars = ...
   ```
2. A nested list is not a very comfortable type to work with. We will define some helper functions
   to make it easier. The operation that we will surely need is *"indexing"*, that is, accessing an
   element by its index — if it is there in the first place.

   ```
   lookup2DMaybe :: [[a]] -> (Int, Int) -> Maybe a
   lookup2DMaybe u (i, j) = do
       xs' <- lookupMaybe xs  i
       x   <- ...
       return x
     where
       lookupMaybe :: [a] -> Int -> Maybe a
       lookupMaybe xs i
           | 0 <= i && i < length xs = ...
           | ...                     = ...
   ```
3. Now, to interesting stuff — stencil application.

   ```
   applyStencil :: [[Int]] -> (Int, Int) -> Int
   applyStencil u = sum . Data.Maybe.catMaybes . fmap (... u) . stencil
     where
       stencil :: (Int, Int) -> [(Int, Int)]
       stencil (i, j) = [ (i + di, ...) | di <- ..., dj <- ..., (di, dj) /= ... ]
   ```

   Does this work?

   ```
   λ applyStencil (charsToInts sampleInput) (3, 5)
   2
   λ applyStencil (charsToInts sampleInput) (6, 1)
   8
   ```
4. All that is left to do is to *"map"* the stencil all around the minefield. To this end, we are
   going to generate a board where at every point its coordinates are written. I hope somewhere along
   the way you will see why.

   ```
   indices :: [[a]] -> [[(Int, Int)]]
   indices u = [ [ ... | ... ] | ... ]
   ```

   The idea here is that we give it a board of anything, and it creates a board of coordinates of
   the same size.
5. Consider the type we have so far:

   ```
   λ :type applyStencil (charsToInts sampleInput) 
   applyStencil (charsToInts sampleInput) :: (Int, Int) -> Int
   ```

   So, this is a function that converts coordinates to the number of mines around these
   coordinates. What happens if we map it over a board of coordinates?

   ```
   fill :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
   fill u = (fmap.fmap) (... u) (... u)

   λ intsToChars (fill (charsToInts sampleInput))
   ["1110000","1011110","1122110","0011221","2332110","2422011","4843000","2422000"]
   ```

   Looks about right, does it not?
6. Only small things left to do: given two boards of characters, overlay them. This is outlined in
   [an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58685116) about lists of lists. *(We get a lot of of questions of this
   kind of late. Say hi to your professor from the Stack Overflow Haskell Teacher's Assistants
   Team!)*
7. Final solution!

   ```
   minesweeper x = overlay x (intsToChars . fill . charsToInts $ x)
   ```

   Not hard at all!

---

There are some ways to improve this code:

1. Create a specialized type for the board, such that only correct boards can be constructed.
2. Define a comonad for that type.
3. Scratch the type altogether and generalize the code to the Store comonad.
4. Use efficient array processing.

But the ideas we explored are there to last.

Some further reading:

1. [The basics of stencil convolution.](https://jaspervdj.be/posts/2014-11-27-comonads-image-processing.html)
2. [The use of standard comonad types.](http://blog.ielliott.io/comonad-transformers-in-the-wild/)
3. [Advanced optimization of stencil convolution.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Stencil.pdf)

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Alright, this looks very promising. However, I think I need several things explained first in order to even try putting it to use. I have not encountered . operator and am unsure what function applies to what. Is it possible to rewrite it without dots?
I also didnt figure out how to turn on -fdefer-typed-holes and didnt quite understand what is in the link you attached. Also, you didn't need to leave holes. Its not about whether it is boring but about me being able to understand what I should need to do.
Also, what other approaches could I take if I wanted to avoid stencil?
Thanks for help

Comment: @JakubKudlej Dot operator is simply function composition. I do not think it makes sense to avoid it in Haskell. You can supply `-fdefer-typed-holes` to `ghc` as a command line argument, or you can say `:set -fdefer-typed-holes` in `ghci`. You cannot really avoid stencil, because it is in the very definition of your problem. Overall, I do not think it gets any simpler than this. I gave you structure, separated the problem into small chunks. If you find any particular subproblem too hard, you can ask a precise question about it. I really want to help you, but you have got to learn Haskell, too.

Comment: Should that be `stencil (i,j)` at the end of the `applyStencil` line? It seems like you eta reduced it but only on one side.

Comment: Stencil convolution on nested lists, that's intense ;) @Jakub Kudlej, once you are ready for the 4th optimization step, you can start over here: https://github.com/lehins/massiv#stencil There are some examples on how to create your own stencils and apply them to actual arrays. Arrays in Haskell are slightly more involved than lists, so I'd recommend to understand this answer first.

Comment: @Potato44 Thanks for catching this.

Comment: Alright, tried to do the first step although it's probably wrong.    

charsToInts :: [[Char]] -> [[Int]]
charsToInts = (fmap . fmap) charToInt
  where
    charToInt '*' = 1
    charToInt ' ' = 0

intsToChars :: [[Int]] -> [[Char]]
intsToChars = (fmap . fmap) intToChar
    where   
        intToChar 0 = '0'
        intToChar 1 = '1'
        intToChar 2 = '2'
        intToChar 3 = '3'
        intToChar 4 = '4'
        intToChar 5 = '5'
        intToChar 6 = '6'
        intToChar 7 = '7'
        intToChar 8 = '8'

Comment: anyways,here is my attempt on indices: indices::[[a]] -> [[(Int, Int)]]
indices ((x:xs):ys) = [[(c,r)|c<-[0..(length(x:xs))]]|r<-[0..(length((x:xs):ys))]]

Comment: @JakubKudlej See, not hard at all!

Comment: I don't think I did what we need in chars to ints and ints to char part though

Comment: @JakubKudlej I put your code in the program and it worked. What makes you think it does not?

Comment: another small error, `pp` shouldn't be included in the definition of `minesweeper`

Comment: @Potato44 True.

Comment: @JakubKudlej please put your attempts above, and leave them out of the comments section. Putting that in the comments section makes it difficult for future readers to get value from your question.